# How to knit a greek symbol in R-studio to generate a pdf

Tags: r, pdf-generation, knitr, pandoc, tex

I am working with R studio markdown and knitr, all together great stuff.

I seem not to be able to knit a greek symbol into pdf.

Same Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Hugo Koopmans"
date: "11-01-2015"
output: pdf_document
---


Test Greek symbol
----------------

P-value
In statistics, the p-value is a function of the observed sample results (a statistic) that is used for testing a statistical hypothesis. Before performing the test a threshold value is chosen, called the significance level of the test, traditionally 5% or 1% [1] and denoted as α. If the p-value is equal or smaller than the significance level (\alpha)
```

Now I am on linx mint 17 texlive 2013 Rstudio Version 0.98.1062

Result:

```
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc Preview-25df24aa1731.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output Preview-25df24aa1731.pdf --template /home/hugo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 


processing file: Preview-25df24aa1731.Rmd
output file: Preview-25df24aa1731.knit.md

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:α not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.73 denoted as α

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

The result is pandoc complaining about the the alpha symbol. So the latex generated seems not to be able to handle the symbol...

I would like to have R studio handle this properly without going into changing the tex file by hand ...ideally...

Any tips?

hugo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For greek symbols in Rmarkdown you can use inline formulas, indicated by `$ ... $`, i.e. two `$` signs.

Try this:

`If the p-value is equal or smaller than the significance level $\alpha$`

[image]